# How to repaint small portion of drawing in JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I have `JPanel` that paints a table in `paintComponent` method:

```
public class PondPanel extends JPanel implements Observer{
    private int numberfRows = 0;
    private int numberfColumns = 0;
    private Dimension size;

    public PondPanel() {
        super();

        size = new Dimension(500, 500);
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    /*
     * Draws initial board without characters.
     * 
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see javax.swing.JComponent#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)
     */
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        if (numberfColumns == 0 || numberfRows == 0) {
            return;
        }
        int cellWidth = size.width / numberfColumns;
        int cellHeight = size.height / numberfRows;

        // drawing initial board
        for (int i = 0; i < numberfRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numberfColumns; j++) {
                int y = i * cellHeight;
                int x = j * cellWidth;
                g.drawRect(x, y, cellWidth, cellHeight);
            }
        }
    }
```

I need method to update only portion of this drawing. Actually I want to do this:

```
g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x * width, y * height, width, height);
```

That's all. I don't want to call `repaint()` to make `paintComponent` run. I only want to repaint a rectangle within drawing in `paintComponent`.

Comment: May I ask you why?

Comment: Swing will do all the work (i.e. optimising out unneeded painting work) if you make each square a component.

Comment: Yes. I want to repaint only one small rectangle because if I repaint each time all rectangles it will be very slow

Comment: (1-) `if I repaint each time all rectangles it will be very slow` - did you try it?

Comment: No. but each rectangle has corresponding swing timer that animates it every second or less. Repainting all when only one needs to be repainted seems stupid

Comment: @JaySmith It is not stupid at all. If you have zillions of columns and lines, and only some of the cells must be updated, maybe I would agree with you, but I think it is not your problem. As teppic said, if you want a really fine tunning of what needs to be repainted you should use components and repaint them.

Comment: Got it. I will try to call repaint() on panel

Comment: @JaySmith Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), it has a section on paint optimisation. Alternatively, you could use a backing buffer, like a `BufferedImage`, update that and then paint it to the component (via `repaint`)